# Unconfirmed transaction emptied my electrum wallet. How can I unstuck it?

Tags: electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

I was using an old Electrum wallet. I sweeped the wallet in a single transaction for which I had not turned on "dynamic wallet" (RBF) yet. The transaction is still unconfirmed after one week. I cannot create another transaction as the wallet is now empty and as I said, RBF had not been activated for the transaction.

I need help recovering my bitcoins, and I'm not finding instructions on how to unstuck the transaction. Could you please provide detailed instructions on how to retrieve my balance?

TXID: 6d75a7d55eee0b1974f5c89cafcd1b983f99e04e48059d84b3c03dd109e7de81

Note, that this is not a duplicate of the canonical question.

Comment: I'm sorry that your question was closed at first. We get about a dozen questions about unconfirmed questions every day most of which are just the generic simple case. You have an edge case here, which we haven't properly covered yet, so I've edited your post to include the relevant information and reopened it.

Comment: This describes a method that would probably work. Please be sure to create a backup before trying it. https://steemit.com/bitcoin/@profitgenerator/tutorial-how-to-fix-unconfirmed-transactions

Comment: that is too complicated. I guess my 125 dollars is lost forever.

Comment: As an alternative you could try to import your electrum wallet from the seed words on another device. The other device should not know about the transaction, so you should be able to create another to recover them.

Comment: nope the nonconfirmed transaction shows up on my android electrum as well. I will pay someone 10 bucks to get this done.

Comment: was that wallet established before you created the transaction or did you create it later? Perhaps the Electrum server still had it and relayed it to the Android wallet. Anyway, yeah getting someone to help you might be a good idea.

Comment: I just downloaded the wallet on my phone now. but the unconfirmed transaction showed up after it synchronized. Thats what im here trying to get help for. I dont know where else to go.

Comment: im at the point where i just want to burn down all bitcoin. this is just ridiculus.

Comment: do you want my seed?

Comment: That seems a bit rash. Please don't post your seed publicly.

Comment: i dont care. its stuck anyway, not llike they can fix it.

Comment: Fees may go down again next week, Electrum may finally implement an "abandonTransaction" feature, there are a few ways this can resolve itself. Also, as long as the transaction doesn't confirm, you're essentially still the owner of the bitcoins. If it confirms, it is where you wanted it to be sent in the first place. So, just let it rest for a bit and approach it fresh in a few days. :)

Comment: I dont have a few days. im killing myself for being stupid. save the world oxygen.

Comment: You haven't lost the bitcoins. Transactions are binary: either they went through or they didn't. In the first case, you transferred successfully, in the latter case you're still the owner of the coins. This will resolve itself one way or another, no reason to become too frustrated about it. Bitcoin has been a learning experience for all of us, it still makes me feel stupid every once in a while as well.

Comment: the transaction doesnt exist on blackchain anymore. it is stuck forever. posting my seed on a new question. thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm afraid that is factually incorrect. Blockchain.info is just a website, not the blockchain itself. If the transaction hasn't confirmed, the money is still in your wallet. I suggest that you refrain from posting your seed, but it's up to you.

Comment: Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database.

Comment: Yeah, that means that blockchain.info is no longer tracking your unconfirmed transaction. Which in turn means less obstacles to reclaiming your coins.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59148/discussion-on-question-by-david-sherrill-unconfirmed-transaction-emptied-my-elec).